# Inner join for two tables - with predicates on the big table

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, indexing, postgresql-performance

Postgresql 9.3

I have two tables `data_prf` with 200.000 and `data_prf_norm` with 22M of records.

```
SELECT n.k AS code, count(n.k) AS total 
FROM data_prf p 
INNER JOIN data_prf_norm n ON (p.data_prf_id = n.data_prf_id) 
WHERE (n.questionid = 5) AND (n.v = 1) 
GROUP BY n.k
```

Obs. Table data_prf_norm has 20M records with v = 0, and 2M records v = 1.

It takes around 3-5 seconds.

```
HashAggregate  (cost=378204.02..378204.08 rows=6 width=2)

->  Hash Join  (cost=100608.78..364361.49 rows=2768506 width=2)

    Hash Cond: (n.data_prf_id = p.data_prf_id)

    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on data_prf_norm n  (cost=51824.36..230655.68 rows=2768506 width=6)

          Recheck Cond: (questionid = 5)

          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on data_prf_norm_questionid_v_idx  (cost=0.00..51132.23 rows=2768506 width=0)

                Index Cond: (questionid = 5)

    ->  Hash  (cost=44584.42..44584.42 rows=256000 width=4)

          ->  Index Only Scan using data_prf_pkey on data_prf p  (cost=0.42..44584.42 rows=256000 width=4)"
```

Is there any way to make it fast?

1) There is only logical integrity, so there is no odd records in data_prf_norm

2) data_prf.data_prf_id yes is unique and primary key.

3) yes data_prf_norm.k is NOT NULL

4) I have created all indexes

```
    CREATE INDEX data_prf_norm_data_prf_id_idx ON data_prf_norm USING btree (data_prf_id) 
    CREATE INDEX data_prf_norm_k_idx ON data_prf_norm USING btree (k);
    CREATE INDEX data_prf_norm_questionid_idx ON data_prf_norm USING btree (questionid);  
    CREATE INDEX data_prf_norm_v_idx ON data_prf_norm USING btree (v);
```

This is the indexes I've used. Is there any other missing index to make it fast? I am supposing 22M is not that big, or I should consider it is a big table?

Thanks.

Comment: It would help to have the table definitions with indexes. However, since you're walking through ~2,768,406 rows it will never be lightning fast. Have you considered doing some denormalization?

Comment: Is it possible that `data_prf p` table is redundant in this query? From the query and the plan it looks like so (but we don't know about your data anything)

Comment: Consider the tag info of the tag I added: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info. Most importantly, we need table definitions with all relevant details and your version of Postgres. And some explanation for your query. Which of the conditions are stable? (Always `n.v = 1`?)

Comment: No sometimes n.v = 0, in that case I am not going to use then.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming missing details:

- referential integrity (no `data_prf_norm.data_prf_id` is missing in `data_prf`)
- `data_prf.data_prf_id` is unique (the PK?). So we have a 1:1 or 1:n relationship between `data_prf` and `data_prf_norm` and not the other way round.
- `data_prf_norm.k` is defined `NOT NULL`.

```
SELECT k AS code, count(*) AS total 
FROM   data_prf_norm
WHERE  questionid = 5
AND    v = 1
GROUP  BY k;
```

#### Major points

- Most importantly, with referential integrity guaranteed, you do not need to join to `data_prf` at all. All predicates are on `data_prf_norm`.
- If `k` is defined `NOT NULL`, you can use the simpler and slightly faster `count(*)`.
- For best read performance create a multi-column ("covering") index:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON data_prf_norm (v, question_id, k);
  ```
- Further assuming that most or all queries include the predicate `v = 1`, use a partial index instead:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX ON data_prf_norm (question_id, k) WHERE v = 1;
  ```

Comment: @PaulHodel: All this information (plus the missing table definition) should better go into the question. Use the edit feature (left under your question). Comments with code are hard to read. Then leave a short comment under my answer to get my attention.